# Socket IO: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, socket.io, arduino, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a web interface to interact with the Arduino Uno, using the [Arduino Create Agent](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-create-agent/wiki/How-to-use-the-agent). I had to use [SocketIO](https://socket.io/docs/v4) for that. The tutorial on the wiki page for the agent asked me to write this line of JavaScript, which produced 2 errors like this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8992/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1621252158361-0' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

socket.io.min.js:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8992/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1621252158274-0 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

I traced the issue and found out that the error was coming from an `XmlHttpRequest`. **I was able to get rid of the first error by forwarding my port using [Localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/), but the second error remains.** Is there any way that I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to allow CORS in your response headers

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf